# ASP.NET - Dynamic Rows and Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, postback, dynamic-controls

I am having a problem with an C# ASP.NET form.  The purpose of the form is to load some key/value pairs from a database to allow a user to view, edit or delete them.

The Key/Value pairs are dynamically generated in the Page_Load event, and everything works well when the page is first openend.  Here is some example code (trimmed down from the original)

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Text = keyName;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
cell = new TableCell();
cell.Text = keyValue;
row.Cells.Add(cell);
KeyValueTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

I just loop through all of the Key/Value pairs and each are added dynamically to a table.  At the point of page loading, everything is running smoothly, and all Key/Value pairs show as expected.

The problem occurs when a user clicks a button, which since is set to runat="server", generates a post back event.  What this does is it appears to do is clear the dynamic content generated above, and then recreates it (since it is created in the Page_Load event).

What I would prefer to do is choose when that dynamic content is cleared, since I don't want it refreshing unnecessarily, since each refresh is actually occurring from a database.

What I have attempted to do is perform the generation of the dynamic content if it isn't a postback.  I.E:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GenerateDynamicContent();
    }
}
```

However what that now does is generate the dynamic content when the page first loads, however as soon as some postback event occurs (such as a user clicking a button), the dynamic content is wiped, but not created.

Basically what I am hoping for is to discover some way where I can create dynamic content, as shown above, that isn't wiped on any postback event.  I want to be able to control when it is refreshed, rather than it occurring on any postback event.  Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: there are many ways 
1. try to put that datatable in viewstate and check for null in the postback
2. put some hidden field on the form and check. if(!IsPostBack && hiddenfield1.value) that might help you

Answer (score 0):

I've found that putting the dynamic code into Page_Init instead of Page_Load prevents the content from being wiped during a postback